# serilog not creating log files

Tags: .net-core, serilog, serilog-exceptions

we are using the following piece of serilog code which writes events to console and file, the file and console logging works fine on my machine, but in the other developers machine console logging works but the file logging does not work and to add to the weirdness the"logs" folder gets created though. Is there any extra setup that needs to be done ?

```
   public static void SetupLogger()
        {
            //var outputTemplate =   "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}";
            var outputTemplate = "[{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}";

            // Logger  
            //var outputTemplate = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u4}] | {Message:l}{NewLine}{Exception}";
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: outputTemplate, theme:SystemConsoleTheme.Literate,restrictedToMinimumLevel:LogEventLevel.Information)
                .WriteTo.File($"logs/log-{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.fff}.log")              
                .CreateLogger();

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first step when troubleshooting any issue with Serilog is to [turn on the `SelfLog`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics) and see if there are any exceptions being caught. The error messages might give you a clue of what's the problem.

```
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(s => Console.WriteLine($"Internal Error with Serilog: {s}"));
```

Alternatively, if you didn't have a Console Window, you could also [use a Notepad window](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-notepad) to inspect the [SelfLog](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-notepad#debugging-and-diagnostics).

---

Anyway, are the machines where it doesn't work running Windows? I ask because looking at your code, I wouldn't expect it to work on Windows because you're saving the file with `:` (colon) in the name which is not a valid character for file names in Windows.

[image: invalid characters for files on Windows]